# Combining multiple data-frame columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to combine 2 data frames columns into 1 but when I try to do it based on specific size the second data-frame column doesn't copy correctly.

I have tried the code below as pasted below.

```
import pandas as pd
def readDataFile():
    fileName = "year.csv"
    dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    dfY = pd.read_csv(fileName, parse_dates=['date'], date_parser=dateparse)

    fileName = "month.csv"
    dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    dfM = pd.read_csv(fileName, parse_dates=['date'], date_parser=dateparse)


    newDF = pd.DataFrame()
    newDF['date_y'] = dfY['date']
    newDF['year_y_n'] = dfY['Y_N']
    newDF['date_m'] = dfM['date'][len(dfM) - len(dfY):len(dfM)]
    newDF['year_y_n'] = dfM['Y_N'][len(dfM) - len(dfY):len(dfM)]
    print newDF
readDataFile()
```

File: month.csv

```
date,Y_N
2018-03-14 04:00:00,N
2018-04-03 04:00:00,N
2018-05-31 04:00:00,Y
2018-06-14 04:00:00,N
2018-07-30 04:00:00,N
2018-08-31 04:00:00,Y
2018-09-28 04:00:00,N
2018-10-10 04:00:00,N
2018-11-07 04:00:00,Y
2018-12-31 04:00:00,N
2019-01-31 04:00:00,N
2019-02-05 04:00:00,Y
2019-03-29 04:00:00,N
2019-04-30 04:00:00,Y
2019-05-03 04:00:00,N
2019-06-03 04:00:00,Y
```

File: year.csv

```
date,Y_N
2014-05-23 04:00:00,Y
2015-12-21 04:00:00,N
2016-05-03 04:00:00,Y
2017-12-20 04:00:00,N
2018-06-14 04:00:00,N
2019-06-25 04:00:00,N
```

These are the CURRENT results:

```
date_y year_y_n date_m month_y_n
0 2014-05-23 04:00:00        Y    NaT       NaN
1 2015-12-21 04:00:00        N    NaT       NaN
2 2016-05-03 04:00:00        Y    NaT       NaN
3 2017-12-20 04:00:00        N    NaT       NaN
4 2018-06-14 04:00:00        N    NaT       NaN
5 2019-06-25 04:00:00        N    NaT       NaN
```

Expected results are:

```
date_y              year_y_n    date_m              month_y_n
2014-05-23 04:00:00        Y  2019-01-31 04:00:00       N
2015-12-21 04:00:00        N  2019-02-05 04:00:00       Y
2016-05-03 04:00:00        Y  2019-03-29 04:00:00       N
2017-12-20 04:00:00        N  2019-04-30 04:00:00       Y
2018-06-14 04:00:00        N  2019-05-03 04:00:00       N
2019-06-25 04:00:00        N  2019-06-03 04:00:00       Y
```

Comment: Can you explain your desired merging logic here?  I can't tell if `len(dfM) - len(dfY):len(dfM)` is doing what you want, or if it's part of the problem.

Comment: I was just trying to get the same amount of monthly columns as yearly length of df. since I want to combine them both.

Comment: Okay.  Still not totally clear why this would be useful (since I would imagine the dates should match in some way).  But my answer below will hopefully solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the index.
If you run the code below:

```
newDF = pd.DataFrame()
newDF['date_y'] = dfY['date']
print(newDF)
```

You will get the output:

```
     date_y
0 2014-05-23 04:00:00
1 2015-12-21 04:00:00
2 2016-05-03 04:00:00
3 2017-12-20 04:00:00
4 2018-06-14 04:00:00
5 2019-06-25 04:00:00
```

The index is starting from 0

And running this:

```
newDF = pd.DataFrame()
newDF['date_m'] = dfM['date'][len(dfM) - len(dfY):len(dfM)]
print(newDF)
```

You will get the output:

```
    date_m
10 2019-01-31 04:00:00
11 2019-02-05 04:00:00
12 2019-03-29 04:00:00
13 2019-04-30 04:00:00
14 2019-05-03 04:00:00
15 2019-06-03 04:00:00
```

Here, the index is starting from 10

So, you need to reset the index of the columns 'date' and 'Y_N' of dfM dataframe,like this:

```
def readDataFile():
    fileName = "year.csv"
    dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    dfY = pd.read_csv(fileName, parse_dates=['date'], date_parser=dateparse)

    fileName = "month.csv"
    dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    dfM = pd.read_csv(fileName, parse_dates=['date'], date_parser=dateparse)


    newDF = pd.DataFrame()
    newDF['date_y'] = dfY['date']
    newDF['year_y_n'] = dfY['Y_N']

    # Changes made on this line.
    newDF['date_m'] = dfM['date'][len(dfM) - len(dfY):len(dfM)].reset_index(drop=True)
    newDF['month_y_n'] = dfM['Y_N'][len(dfM) - len(dfY):len(dfM)].reset_index(drop=True)

    print(newDF)
readDataFile()
```

Output:

```
date_y year_y_n              date_m month_y_n
0 2014-05-23 04:00:00        Y 2019-01-31 04:00:00         N
1 2015-12-21 04:00:00        N 2019-02-05 04:00:00         Y
2 2016-05-03 04:00:00        Y 2019-03-29 04:00:00         N
3 2017-12-20 04:00:00        N 2019-04-30 04:00:00         Y
4 2018-06-14 04:00:00        N 2019-05-03 04:00:00         N
5 2019-06-25 04:00:00        N 2019-06-03 04:00:00         Y
```

Comment: Why does Index matter, when I really am just trying to copy the column data?

Comment: Because you are copying data indexed from 10-15 (Dataframe dfM) to newDF (which is being stored in newDF in the index 10-15) and another column indexed from 0 to 5 (Dataframe dfY) to newDF(which is being stored in newDF in the index 0-5), while the remaning values of 'date_m' and 'month_y_n' (indexed from 0-5 are coming out to be Nan) since there values are stored in index 10-15.

Comment: Hope this helps!

Comment: I just thought that since I am only looking to copy column values indexes are irrelevant. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Yes it did.  Thanks for you help again. How do I select it as solution?

Comment: You can click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have an arbitrary number of dataframes `dfA`, `dfB`, `dfC`, etc.  You want to merge them, but they're different sizes.  The most basic approach is to concatenate them:

```
df = pd.concat([dfA, dfB, dfC], axis=1)
```

But if the dataframes are different sizes, there will be missing rows.  If you don't care which rows are preserved, you can just drop rows with missing values:

```
df.dropna()
```

But if you specifically want to use the last *N* rows of each dataframe, where *N* is the length of the smallest dataframe, you need to do a little more work.  But I'll wait and see if that's what you want.

---

**Old Answer:**

Merging can be much simpler than this.  Use [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html):

```
pd.merge(dfY, dfM[-len(dfY):].reset_index(), 
    suffixes=['_y', '_m'], left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

- `dfM[-len(dfY):]` gets the last *N* rows of `dfM`, where *N* is the length of `dfY`.
- `.reset_index()` makes the index of the subset of `dfM` start at 0, so it can correctly align with `dfY`.
- `suffixes=['_y', '_m']` keeps the column names different.  You can rename these if you like.

Comment: so what do I do if I have more than 2.. I have 4 that I would like to merge, for instance, dfQ, dfW.

Comment: For the future, make a requirement like this clear in the question if you can.

Comment: Also, do you care whether it's the first or last rows of `dfY` that you merge, or can it just be the right number of rows?

Comment: Sorry, that I didn't make it clear that had more than 2 dfs.  I did that so I don't cause any confusion.  I'm sorry I am not understanding the question.

Comment: Try `df = pd.concat([dfA, dfB, dfC], axis=1)`.  Does that work for you?

Comment: Not really. because it prints what ever length is max. and merges them, rest gets NaN.  Also, I have more than 2 columns that I would like to avoid merging.. I only want to merge 2 columns

Comment: doesn't work. It doesn't give me expected results. it drops last rows of month.csv which I actually need.